# break statement is not exiting the loop

Tags: c++

this is a guess the number game ... the problem is that the "if" clause in the main function has break; statement and it is is not working properly... its purpose is that whenever the user guess is correct it displays the appropriate message and then exits the loop.... but somehow the break statement is not exiting it just continues to the next iteration

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int computer_number(){
    int number;    
    
    number=(rand() % 10)+1;      

    return number;
}

string result(int user , int computer){
    if(user == computer)
    {
        return ("User guess matched\n\n\n\nyyyaaaaayyyyyyyyyy!!!!!!");
    }
    else
    {
        return ("guess is not correct\n");
    }        
}

int main(){
    int counter=1;
    string r;
    cout<<"Welcome  to guess the number game...!!!!!!!!"<<endl;
              
    int correct_number;
    correct_number = computer_number();
    cout<<"computer has choosen the number"<<endl;

    cout<<"\n\n";
    while(true){                           
          
            cout<<"\n\n\n"<<"Please guess a number between 1 to 10, you have 10 chances ... best of luck..!!!!"<<endl;
            int user_number = 0;
            cin>>user_number;
            cout<<"you chose "<<user_number<<endl;
            cout<<"\n\n\n"<<endl;
            cout<<"let's see if it is corect..."<<endl;
            
            r = result(user_number,correct_number);

            cout<<r;   
            if(r=="User guess matched")
            {
                cout<<"You have guessed the number in "<<counter<<" times";
                cout <<endl;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                counter++;
                cout<<"\n\n\nturn: "<<counter<<"\n\n";
                if (counter>10)
                {
                    cout<<"you only had 10 chances"<<endl;
                    cout<<"you lost"<<endl;
                    break;
                }                
            }     
            }
    
    return 0;
}
```

the problem is with :

```
if(r=="User guess matched")
            {
                cout<<"You have guessed the number in "<<counter<<" times";
                cout <<endl;
                break;
            }
```

this snippet, it is not exitting the while loop whereas the else clause is working fine

Comment: why are you returning a string from result? just return true or false

Comment: `r` is either `""User guess matched\n\n\n\nyyyaaaaayyyyyyyyyy!!!!!!""` or `"guess is not correct\n"` but never `"User guess matched"`... There is no possible way to enter this `if`.

Comment: is there any issue if i return string instead of boolean?

Comment: result() return one of two strings. None of them is "User guess matched".

Comment: hmm.. let me see

Comment: Using `while (True)` is not a good practice at all. Try something like `while (gameStatus)` and try to control the loop in that way. If you want to not iterate loop, then instead of that `break` you can say `gameStatus = False;`

Comment: thank you churill !!!

Comment: @FarbodAhmadian I don't think `while (true)` is that bad really, and I question whether having to have another variable in scope and deal with initialising/assigning the right values is much better really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code can never enter that `if` branch.

There are two possible outcomes of `result()` function:
`"User guess matched\n\n\n\nyyyaaaaayyyyyyyyyy!!!!!!"` or `"guess is not correct\n"`. Neither of them is equal to `"User guess matched"`.

You should strongly avoid comparing strings for code flow, for this exact reason. Simple typo or change can break your program silently, and compiler won't be able to help you.

The correct type to use here is `bool`:

```
bool result(int user , int computer){
    return user == computer;
}
```

In main:

```
bool r = result(user_number,correct_number);

if(r)
{
    //print some congratulations to the user
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`result` returns a string that is either `"User guess matched\n\n\n\nyyyaaaaayyyyyyyyyy!!!!!!"` or `"guess is not correct\n"`. One of these values will be in `r`.

You are checking to see if `r` is equal to `"User guess matched"`. The problem is that computers are *very* literal about things. They check comparisons exactly. It's not enough for strings to be similar, they must be the same. Of course, `"User guess matched"` is *not* the same as `"User guess matched\n\n\n\nyyyaaaaayyyyyyyyyy!!!!!!"`.

In summary, you need to change your `if` clause to:

```cpp
if(r=="User guess matched\n\n\n\nyyyaaaaayyyyyyyyyy!!!!!!")
            {
                cout<<"You have guessed the number in "<<counter<<" times";
                cout <<endl;
                break;
            }
```

Edit:

a few more points I would make:

- It's obvious that you're new to programming. If you want to take the route of writing a function to return whether the user has been successful, I would suggest making it return a `bool` - a 'yes' or 'no', in computer terms. Except, we use the words `true` or `false`, which have special meanings as 'yes' and 'no' respectively. For example:

```cpp
bool result(int user, int computer){
    return user == computer;    // yes, you can do this!   
}

int main() {
    // ...
    bool res;
    while(true) {                           
        // ...
        res = result(user_number,correct_number);
        if (res) {
            cout << "You have guessed the number in " << counter << " times" << endl;
            break;
        } else {
            counter++;
            cout << "\n\n\nturn: " << counter << "\n\n";
            if (counter > 10) {
                cout << "you only had 10 chances" << endl;
                cout << "you lost" << endl;
                break;
            }                
        }     
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

- Professional C++ programmers will look at that and still shiver, because there's a lot more that could be done with it. For a start, there's no need for the `result` function. Secondly, if you have a `counter` variable, then a `for` loop might be the way to go. The `res` variable is also fairly redundant here.
- You'll also notice I've also changed the way the code is layed out. That's because, while you may want to follow your own code style, you'll find it a lot easier to work with other people in the future when you write code that looks similar to theirs. The way I've written it is pretty standard.

Answer (score 1):

there probably is an easier solution but u could just make a boolean that is set to false instead of using a break, and in the while loop instead of using while(true) use while(myboolean) which is the same  as while(myboolean ==true)

Comment: I don't think `while (true)` is that bad really, and I question whether having to have another variable in scope and deal with initialising/assigning the right values is much better really. Anyway, their problem is the test for whether to `break` or 'break', and that's wrong, so using a variable instead won't solve that.